# How can I develop an API in nestJS that uses simultaneous Express and RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
 });
 
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
transport: Transport.RMQ,
options: {
urls: "amqps://user:pass@localhost",
queue: "queue",
queueOptions: {
durable: true,
 },
 },
 });
```

My api needs to received a JSON from httpRequest and then send a push to RabbitMQ

Comment: Your server would be a RabbitMQ client, right? As in you need to push things to RabbitMQ, not consume the RabbitMQ calls, right?

Comment: Yes push to Rabbit no need to read anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're needing to to make calls **to** RabbitMQ, then you can use the `ClientsModule` and create a microservice client as a part of your REST server, [as described in the docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#client). You can add this to your imports:

```js
ClientsModule.register([
  {
    name: 'RABBIT_SERVICE',
    transport: Transport.RabbitMQ,
    options: {
      urls: "amqps://user:pass@localhost",
      queue: "queue",
      queueOptions: {
        durable: true,
      },
    },
  },
])
```

And now you Can use `@Inject('RABBIT_SERVICE')` to inject the RabbitMQ Client in your provider